# i have a challenge relating what should be primary key and foreign key in my database tables

Tags: mysql

i am designing database tables for a real estate company. my head is clogged up .i cant figure out how to decide which columns will become primary keys,foreign keys and/or composite keys.

i have four tables; location, floors , typeOfProperty and features.
location table is the most basic table that has columns; locationLong, locationLat,locationName and propertyName. locationlong is the primary key in this table.
i created the location table and used locationlong as primary key because i figured out that every point on earth has a unique location Longitude.this is if i consider that positive and negative values are always unique.(i stand to be collected).

i have noted however that there are situations where i would want to identify a property on a certain location that has a building that has more than one floor.therefore i would like to figure out how my floors table needs to be constructed. i am thinking of having a location long column and a second 
 column called floor number such that both these columns will make composite primary key of this table.

There is a third table called typeOfProperty. this is the table where i want to have different columns that select the type of property that can be on a particular floor. i.e a floor can have many houses to buy, many houses to let, a commercial property to sell, etc. so i have created the following columns;

```
hseBuyOrLetOrFurn ENUM('buy', 'let', 'furn') - SELECT IF HOUSE IS TO BUY, LET, 
                                               OR FULLY FURNISHED    
comspaceBuyOrLease ENUM('buy', 'lease') - TO SELECT IF COMMERCIAL SPACE IS BUY 
                                           OR LEASE
cost INT -- TO CAPTURE COST OF PROPERTY ETC.
```

i would want to know what to use as primary key in this table.

there is a third table called general features . this table has columns that has columns that show the features of a particular type of property e.g it has a column for No of bedrooms, cctv,swimming pool, bathrooms,lifts, etc.
i have other similar tables to the general features as shown in the code below.

please assist me to know how i should figure out primary and foreign keys in this table.

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `locationLong` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationLat` decimal(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationName` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `houseNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`locationLong`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `floors` (
  `locationLong` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationLat` decimal(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationName` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ld`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `propertytype` (
  `locationLong` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationLat` decimal(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `hseBuyOrLetOrFurn` enum('buy','let','furn') DEFAULT NULL,
  `bedrooms` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gatedOrSloneOrApart` enum('gated','slone','apart') DEFAULT NULL,
  `hotelOr` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gdwnBuyOrLease` enum('gdwn','lease') DEFAULT NULL,
  `landBuyOrLease` enum('buy','lease') DEFAULT NULL,
  `comspaceBuyOrLease` enum('buy','lease') DEFAULT NULL,
  `twoDImage` blob,
  `threeDImage` blob,
  `vRVideo` blob,
  `cost` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `location_locationLong` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`locationLong`),
  KEY `fk_propertyType_location_idx` (`location_locationLong`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_propertyType_location` FOREIGN KEY (`location_locationLong`) REFERENCES `area` (`locationLong`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `generalfeatures` (
  `locationLong` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationLat` decimal(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `livingAreaAndSize` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bedrooms` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bathrooms` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `masterEnsuite` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `bedroomsWithBathrooms` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `kitchenAndSize` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `parkingAndSlots` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `swimmingPool` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `liftsAndNumber` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `CCTV` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `sizeOfLand` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `borehole` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `propertyType_locationLong` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`locationLong`),
  KEY `fk_generalFeatures_propertyType1_idx` (`propertyType_locationLong`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_generalFeatures_propertyType1` FOREIGN KEY (`propertyType_locationLong`) REFERENCES `propertytype` (`locationLong`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `hotelfeatures` (
  `locationLong` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationLat` decimal(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `conference` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `fibreCable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `spa` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `freshOutdoor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `laundryFacilities` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `entertainment` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `wifi` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `propertyType_locationLong` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`locationLong`),
  KEY `fk_hotelFeatures_propertyType1_idx` (`propertyType_locationLong`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_hotelFeatures_propertyType1` FOREIGN KEY (`propertyType_locationLong`) REFERENCES `propertytype` (`locationLong`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `outdoorfeatures` (
  `locationLong` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL,
  `locationLat` decimal(10,8) NOT NULL,
  `gym` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `matureGardens` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `partyArea` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `gardenAndSize` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `waterFront` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `propertyType_locationLong` decimal(11,8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`locationLong`),
  KEY `fk_outdoorFeatures_propertyType1_idx` (`propertyType_locationLong`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_outdoorFeatures_propertyType1` FOREIGN KEY (`propertyType_locationLong`) REFERENCES `propertytype` (`locationLong`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to have a general idea how the location table that have location details, links to floors table that has details of floor type links to the propertytype table that links to different property type and finally how this property type table links to the generalfeatures, hotel features and indoor features table.

Comment: If you want a database model that matches real life as close as possible. i advice you to use [Fully Communication Oriented Information Modeling (FCO-IM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FCO-IM)

Comment: *"locationlong is the primary key in this table"* Why? This will prevent 2 entries to have the same longitude. If something is moved (for some reasons) You couldn't update that information (A primary key isn't supposed to be changed)

Comment: using `enum`  is generally a bad idea better is to use types tables instead.. That way you don't have to use ALTER to add a new type.

Comment: i used locationLong as primary key becasuse i wanted to index this column. i figured out that when one is searching for property location and price were the most common criteria they will use to search the database,

Comment: thank you for the idea, let me explore it,

Comment: Indexing is nice for **uniques** values.

Answer (score 0):

You have a table to hold property main data (this table later you add to it more fields as required until I get the final design for table)
Ex: main_property_file( property_id PK , address, GPS_location ) 
Then you need to know is it for lease or sale , 
Build lookup table hold this , ex: property_for(typefor PK, name this) 
And going to add a filed in previous main_property_file for typefor filed as foreign key
And so on until you put all business data structure , then going to review the tables and relation for consistency, you can put this in visual tool if you cannot imagine the relation and the data each table hold, and finally ask your model with query to find information or enter new data and so on to be sure your table design is complete and review the **constraints** too.